# WD MyCloud NFS Mount to Asus Merlin Router: NFS mount troubleshooting: "no such device"

Tags: nfs, troubleshooting

Goal: mount a UNIX NAS ([WD myCloud](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/wd-my-cloud-8tb-external-hard-drive-nas-white/5056700.p?skuId=5056700)) to a UNIX router.

What has been done (do not assume it is correct):

1. [Checked router is running NFS client](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-if-nfs-service-running-on-linux-unix-server/):

   ```
   ps | grep nfsd
   ```

   19243 username   1376 R    grep nfsd
2. Checked NAS is running NFS server from macbook:

   ```
   rpcinfo -T udp 192.168.X.XXX | grep nfs
      100003       2     tcp      0.0.0.0.8.1          nfs        unknown
      100003       3     tcp      0.0.0.0.8.1          nfs        unknown
      100003       2     udp      0.0.0.0.8.1          nfs        unknown
      100003       3     udp      0.0.0.0.8.1          nfs        unknown
   ```
3. Attempt to mount NAS directory use syntax:

   mount -t nfs  server_IP_addr:/share_name /local_mount_point

   ```
   mount -t NFS 192.168.X.XXX:/shares/Public/Data /mnt/nas
   ```

   The error response:

> mount: mounting 192.168.X.XXX:/shares/Public/Data/ on /mnt/nas failed:
>   **No such device**

I am interested in understanding how to diagnose the cause of 'no such device'. Is there a procedure (series of command-line tests) that systematically flush out the issue?

## Updates / Detailed Responses to Questions / Requests:

nfs server module not found and unable to load:

```
root@WDMyCloud root # service nfs status
-sh: service: not found
root@WDMyCloud root # systemctl status nfs-server
-sh: systemctl: not found
root@WDMyCloud root # lsmod | grep nfs
root@WDMyCloud root # modprobe nfs
modprobe: chdir(/lib/modules): No such file or directory   
root@WDMyCloud root # ipkg
-sh: ipkg: **not found**
```

`ps` command:

```
root@WDMyCloud root # ps | grep -i nfs
  375 root         0 SW<  [nfsiod]
 2813 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2814 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2815 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2816 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2817 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2818 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2819 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
 2820 root         0 SW   [nfsd]
11491 root      2592 S    grep -i nfs
```

`showmount -e 192.168.X.X`  returns an empty export list

Comment: I'm not sure that NFS-server is started. What service is responsible for NFS-server? Please, show output on: 'systemctl status nfs-server' or 'service nfs status'.

Comment: Also check if the `nfs` module is loaded with `lsmod | grep nfs` or just insert it with `modprobe nfs`. To see more info, you could add `-v` to your mount command.

Comment: @Thomas  Please see update in OP for results.  Server nfs module is not loaded and modprobe fails.  ipkg also fails

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk  Both commands are unavailable and ipkg is unavailable

Comment: @gatorback Hmm... Do you have '/shares/Public/Data' in '/etc/export'? Try to see in logs on NFS-server (/var/log/messages or something else) for events like NFS. What say 'mount -v'? P.S. Maybe it's typo, but no need to write 'nfs' in 'mount' command in uppercase.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk  I do not have an  '/etc/export'.   Lowercase 'nfs' in 'mount' throws a different error  "Bad file descriptor".   'mount -v' | grep nas does not return anything

Comment: Lets try to speak in chat room. I hope it will be more productive. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74402/nfs-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special thanks to **YurijGoncharuk** who spent hours experimenting with NFS.

## How to Mount a WD MyCloud NAS to Asus Merlin Router

- NAS: enable NFS =>WebUI =>Shares =>ShareName =>Share Access =>NFS Access=ON
- Verify NFS shares are available:  showmount -e 192.168.X.XXX
- [enable NFS services in router](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/any-possible-way-to-mount-nfs-shares-on-to-router.27851/)
- [mount -t nfs 192.168.X.XXX:/NFS_share_name/     /mnt/nas                    -o nfsvers=3,nolock,_netdev,rsize=8192,wsize=8192](https://www.snbforums.com/threads/any-possible-way-to-mount-nfs-shares-on-to-router.27851/)
- mount -t nfs 192.168.X.XXX:/mnt/HD/HD_a2/Public /tmp/mnt/sda1/Download2/nas -o nfsvers=3,nolock,_netdev,rsize=8192,wsize=8192
- MacBook Client

  sudo mount_nfs -o resvport IP_Address:/NFS_share_name/ /local_mountpoint

  sudo mount_nfs -o resvport 192.168.X.XXX:/mnt/HD/HD_a2/Public /Users/user/nas

Comment: Don't forget to mark this post as solver. And 'show mount' has typo -  'showmount'.